# Converting Java to Python - attribute value to a string

Tags: java, python

I'm new to python and trying to convert my selenium-Java scripts into selenium-python. I've been struggling to convert below code. Well, this is running successfully with Selenium-Java.

I got stuck wherein i would like to get the attribute value at a particular location and converting it to a string.

```
String indx=element.getAttribute("num");
int k=Integer.parseInt(indx);
element.sendKeys(""+a[k]);
```

How do I get that running in Python?
Thank you

```
char a[]={'0','p','a','s','s','w','o','r','d','1'};

for(int i=1;i<=3;i++) {
    try {

    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("pff"+i));

        if(element != null) {
            String indx=element.getAttribute("num");
            int k=Integer.parseInt(indx);                   
            element.sendKeys(""+a[k]);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){

    }
}
```

Comment: I won't try to do a full answer since I've never used java, but from my read of your code, you seem to be skipping over one of the best features of python: Dynamic typing. You don't need to declare data types at assignment. `a=['0','p','a','s','s','w','o','r','d','1']`, `indx=element.getAttribute("num")`, and `k=int(indx)`. Does that help?

Comment: More concisely it could also be `a = "0password1"`. Also, I think it should be `.get_attribute("num")` for python.

Comment: Thanks @G.Anderson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you should learn python. It is not that difficult if you know Java already. As for the function calls nomenclature in python they are slightly different from [here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-by-id)

I hope this works for you, I don't know selenium but this should work

```
# In python comments are preceded by a hashtag
# In python you don't have to declare the type of a list
# A will be an array of the letters
a = ['0','p','a','s','s','w','o','r','d','1']

# Pay attention to your indentation, you should read up on it
# indentation is very important in python

# loop that goes from 0 to 3 (4 here because it's not inclusive) 
for i in range(0, 4):
    # try statement
    try:
        # in python you don't need to declare the type of a variable
        webElement = driver.find_element_by_id("pff" + str(i))

        if element != None:
            # to get the attribute you call this method
            indx = element.get_attribute("num")

            # this is how you parse in python
            k = int(indx)     

            element.send_keys("" + a[k])
        except: #here you have to check for which error
            print("An error has occurred")
```

And more concisely, it would look like this:

```
a = "0password1"
for i in range(0, 4):
    try:
        if driver.find_element_by_id("pff" + str(i)) != None:
            element.send_keys("" + a[int(element.get_attribute("num"))])
    except:
        print("An error has occurred")
```

Comment: looks like your except is indented too far

Comment: Ah yes, thank you for that. Is there a reason why the tab button doesn't work in the editor? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @AhmadMoussa, Thank you so much for your assistance on this. When i ran it, I got an error as "TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects". I then just changed element = driver.find_element_by_id("pff" + i) to element = driver.find_element_by_id("pff" + str(i)) and it worked successfully.

Comment: @Quinn, Thank you

Comment: @Abhish congrats on solving it. If this helped, consider clicking the check mark left to the answer to accept it and close this question.